# Does local monotonicity implies global monotonicity?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, monotone-functions

Let $f:(-\pi, \pi) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a function such that for every $x \in (-\pi, \pi) $, $f'(x)$ exists and it's positive.

This means that given $x_o \in (-\pi, \pi)$, we have that $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} >0$. This means that exists $r>0$ such that if $x\in(x_0-r, x_0+r)$, then $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} >0$. If $x \in (x_0, x_0 +r)$, then $f(x)-f(x_0) >0$. So there exists $x_1$ such that $f(x_1) > f(x_0)$. Similarly, if $x \in (x_0 - r, x_0)$, then exists $x_2$ such that $f(x_0) > f(x_2)$. We have shown that $f(x_1) > f(x_0) > f(x_2)$, this is what "locally increasing at $x_0$" has been defined to me.

Now, assuming this proof is correct, does this shows/leads to showing that $f$ is increasing?

My teacher has proven that such $f$ is indeed increasing using Lagrange’s Mean Value Theorem, since for every $a, b \in (-\pi, \pi)$, $a<b$, there exists $c \in (-\pi, \pi)$ such that $f(b) - f(a) = f'(c)(b-a)$ and since the right side is positive the left one must also be positive.

This is quick and elegant, but I still have doubts about if the first proof is correct or not, since intuitively I feel like it's correct but I have a hard time going from locally monotonicity to global.

Comment: If the problem statement includes the phrase "for **every** $x\in (−\pi,\pi)$, $f′(x)$ exists and is positive", then in *this* context, local and global (within the interval $ (−\pi,\pi)$) monotonicity are both implied. This would be true even if you replaced "positive" with "negative" above.

See this link:

http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/mtold/txtc/2/txe3ca2c.htm

Comment: In general local monotonicity does *not* imply global monotonicity. Just consider the function $f(x)=\sin(x)$ in the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$, which is locally monotonic within several sub-intervals of $(-\pi,\pi)$, but not globally monotonic in that interval. Conversely however, the global monotonicity of $f(x)=x$ over $\mathbb R$ also implies local monotonicity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SharatVChandrasekhar. I do understand that $f$ is increasing. And I provided the proof using Lagrange's MVT at the end. My difficulty is if the first 'proof' in the main post could lead to showing that $f$ is increasing without the use ofa MVT.